# How to make css background-image a fluid image work in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I had this working in IE9, but then messed it up trying to figure it out in IE8 and 7. I've searched around here and other places, but can not find the correct solution to my problem.

I'm trying to scale an image down in a div whenever the browser window is resized smaller than its max-width (fluid image). I'm assuming the problem is that I'm using a CSS3 property (background-size: 100%;) which is not supported in older browsers. How can I make this compatible to IE9, 8, 7?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 4.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Fluid Image</title>
<style type="text/css">

img {
    max-width: 90%;
    height: auto;
}

.imageContainer {
    width: 900px;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(img/fluidImage.jpg);
    background-position: 0 -450px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 650px;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="imageContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it have to be a background-image?  If you use an ordinary embedded image, you can force it to scale using width/max-width.

Comment: I would like to keep it as a background image just to have this answered for any future problems I may run into.

Comment: There is no `background-size` property support in older browsers. You'll need to use the `<img/>` object in order to get things working.

Comment: I'm beginning to think you guys are right.

Comment: I believe the best solution as of now is to use the <img/> tag as mentioned above, and also use media queries. Thanks cimmanon and Set Sail Media. I did come across a little headache referencing media queries that has been copied and pasted everywheere from [CSS Tricks.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) A reminder, do not forget to place a comma after the media queries or it will not work.

Comment: Also, it helped to place the orientation right after the first and operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a filter you can use for this:

http://www.pziecina.com/design/turorial_demos/resize_background.php

For pre IE8 use -

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='linkToImage.jpg',sizingMethod='scale');
```

For IE8 use:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='linkToImage.jpg',sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Using the sizingMethod= 'scale' means that even IE will scale the background image to the size of the browser window.

Comment: I should of posted this earlier, but I came across those two filters before posting and had a problem with the image's width getting stretched. It seems the filters are not adjusting the height accordingly. Maybe my CSS is wrong? The two filters are only adjusting the images width to 100% of the div. I've been trying to figure out how to scale the height proportionately to the width. Any idea how on how to adjust the height?

Comment: The page I linked to above mentions that those filters dont handle aspect ratio as well as the CSS3 code does so that may be the issue. Also it advises wrapping the filter code in an IE conditional statement to make only IE8 and less use those filters as IE9 should be fine with the CSS3 code afaik.